# An Errno::ENOMEM issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, child-process, spawn

Suddenly on both my staging and prod servers (different but using the same VPS provider) I am receiving the following error when using my ruby rails app:

```
An Errno::ENOMEM occurred in projects#update:

Cannot allocate memory - identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/Lanscape_originalV220140520-32388-1alg9vz.png[0]'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cocaine-0.3.0/lib/cocaine/command_line/runners/process_runner.rb:17:in `spawn’"
```

How can I solve this?

FYI I temporarily solved it by restarting the servers

here is the projects update file causing the issue:

```
class ProjectUpdatesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_project
  def index
    @project_updates = @project.project_updates
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.new
  end

  def show
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.new
  end

  def edit
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.new(params[:project_update])
    @project_update.project = @project
    return redirect_to :back, :alert => 'abc.' unless current_user.owner?(@project_update.project)
      if @project_update.save
        redirect_to project_project_updates_path(@project), :notice => 'abc.'
      else
        redirect_to project_project_updates_path(@project), :alert => 'abc.'
      end
  end

  def update
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
    return redirect_to :back, :notice => 'you cannot edit project update.' unless current_user.owner?(@project_update.project)
      if @project_update.update_attributes(params[:project_update] )
        redirect_to project_project_updates_path(@project), :notice => 'abc.'
      else
        redirect_to project_project_updates_path(@project), :alert => 'abcy.'
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @project_update = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
    return redirect_to :back, :alert => 'abc.' unless current_user.owner?(@project_update.project)
    @project_update.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_project_updates_url(@project) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def get_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def feed
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project_updates = @project.project_updates
    respond_to do |format|
      format.rss { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Post your `update` method. You're doing something that's eating up too much memory.

Comment: hello @tirdadc I have posted the "update" file that may be causing the issue

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `projects#update` somehow triggers a system call to `identify -format ...`. The gem [cocaine](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine) is used for this. It says the following in the readme:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine#posix-spawn

> You can potentially increase performance by installing the posix-spawn gem. This gem can **keep your application's heap from being copied** when forking command line processes. For applications with large heaps the gain can be significant.

I've tested this and reproduced the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'posix/spawn'

@arrays = []

def do_echos
        begin
                IO.popen('echo I am a child started with popen') { |io| puts io.read }
        rescue  Errno::ENOMEM => e
                puts "IO.popen: #{e.message}"
        end

        begin
                pid = Process.spawn('echo I am a child started with Process.spawn')
                Process.wait(pid)
        rescue Errno::ENOMEM => e
                puts "Process.spawn: #{e.message}"
        end

        child = POSIX::Spawn::Child.new('echo', 'I am a child started with posix_spawn');
        puts child.out
end

def fill_mem
        begin
                while true
                        @arrays << Array.new(10000000)
                end
        rescue NoMemoryError
                puts "Allocated arrays until out of memory..."
        end
end

do_echos
fill_mem
do_echos
```

This outputs:

> I am a child started with popen
>   I am a child started with Process.spawn
>   I am a child started with posix_spawn
>   Allocated arrays until out of memory...
>   IO.popen: Cannot allocate memory - echo
>   Process.spawn: Cannot allocate memory - echo
>   I am a child started with posix_spawn

In conclusion, I recommend you follow cocaine's advice.

> To include posix-spawn, simply add it to your Gemfile or, if you don't use bundler, install the gem.

https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn